# Why can't I see public ip on my cloud server?

Tags: ip, cloud

I have recently applied for a cloud-based server. I am not very experienced in system admin. So pardon me if this is silly.

I was using     ifconfig command to view available network interface. But I all I see is this.

```
 eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:48:87:33
          inet addr:10.105.9.247  Bcast:10.105.63.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2316148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:817504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:311812602 (297.3 MiB)  TX bytes:138419228 (132.0 MiB)

 lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

I don't see public ip address. But that is not possible, because I remote logged in to that server using provided ip address.

Here is my question. How could they hide the information? What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: You won't be able to change any of the configuration that could possibly affect other machines in the hosting center where your server is located. Why do you want to change the IP?

Comment: Public IP is defined at the data center level, it would be between your host and their ISP, then down to how they configure their servers.

Comment: This should be directed to the hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously don't have one assigned to your box directly but there's one likely mapped on a firewall in front of your server directing traffic to it (NAT). In the web control panel from your hosting provider there'll likely be a firewall control panel element where rules can be configured.

Background info -

Network Address Translation  (NAT)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation